# Efficient way to store tile ids game

Tags: c#-4.0, game-engine

I was wondering if there are more efficient setups for storing constant values.
I am trying to create a game with many different tile types. My setup is pretty clunky. Right now, I just have a static class specifically for constants. I probably have over 1000 constants. Is there any way to trim it down or take up less space?

Comment: google how to make tile based game engines and you'll find a lot of useful info, including how to simplify your design. Also, as it stands now, your question seriously lacks required info to solve your problem. It's not specific enough, and answers now would be just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Often instead of constants you can use Enums and then use .ToString() of the enum values to convert to a string:

```
public enum Level { Easy, Medium, Hard }
```

instead of

```
public class Level
{
    public const string Easy = "Easy";
    ...
}
```